# Understanding npm ERESOLVE errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Please help me understand a seemingly self-contradicting npm dependency resolution error.

I'm trying to update two dependencies in one of my projects: `eslint` from `6.8.0` to `7.32.0` and `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` from `4.5.12` to `5.0.8`.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: tainted-ref@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/michael.grosse/.npm/_logs/2023-07-05T16_20_32_745Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/michael.grosse/.npm/_logs/2023-07-05T16_20_32_745Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm confused by this, because it reads like everything should be fine:

```js
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">=7.5.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!     dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^5.0.8" from the root project
```

The above part seems to say that `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.8` requires a peer dependency of `eslint` at `7.5.0` or larger. And I'm updating to `eslint` version `7.32.0`. Why is that a conflict?

It would be great if someone could explain the actual underlying problem here, or link to some article that does.

---

Note: I want to *actually understand* what is going on here. I'm aware that I can use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` to accept an *incorrect* (and potentially broken) dependency resolution and move forward. But that is not what I'm looking for here, so please don't suggest it.